# performance of '==' vs '===' (jsperf)

Tags: javascript, performance, firefox, jsperf

I was just browsing the endless list of jsperf tests and looked at the one called 
[== vs === perf](http://jsperf.com/vs-perf). I expected the outcome to be a no-brainer ( === to be faster ) but no, not in FireFox.

Can someone explain to me how Firefox can be so fast and how it is possible that === is more or less equal to == ?

Although [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons) post has a lot in common with my post, it doesn't answer the result Firefox produces!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`==` vs. `===` is not going to make a real-world difference in your code’s performance. This is a microbenchmark.

Check out this presentation by @mraleph, explaining why microbenchmarks are evil and should be avoided: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=65-RbBwZQdU&hd=1 He explains why tests like the one you linked to are basically useless, as engines optimize things like this away.